# How to prevent from misclose browsers

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, jquery

I have a Web Application and I want to get a confirmation from users when they are closing the application no matter what.

I mean I'm looking for a way to display a message touser whenever user try to close the application.

---

**Update :**  I want to use my dialog box not browsers dialogbox. r at least a dialogbox which only shows my message no extra message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for jQuery here, just hook up the window beforeunload event

[Demo](http://pastebin.me/pastebin/_design/pastebin.me/_show/raw/775e7e80c3c09a9f0ad867fa69b68745)

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   return "Are you sure?";
}
```

Comment: I used it before and whenever I refresh the window an error appeared and tell me method cannot found!!!!! where to use it?

Comment: Actually the dialogbox which is appeared is not suitable for me. I want to show Just my text not Browser text too. I'm waiting for your answer. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Apologies for not knowing what your question really was! You cant just change the context of a question, the answer suits your question.

Comment: you cannot change the dialog because it is how browsers implement the event. There is no way to do what your asking in your comment